# Rig distorting objects separately instead of together

Tags: rigging

I've been trying to find answers to this all night but i'm having no luck so I thought i'd ask here.
[image]

I've been trying to learn rigging, following video tutorials etc. But i've ran into a serious roadblock
[image]
[image]

As you can see, despite the eyes and mouth being part of the same object as the face, instead of turning with it, they morph and distort off in random directions. The right hand side seems to move with the arm, and the left hand side seems to move with shoulders.
I can't for the life of me figure out where I've gone wrong with the rigging process.
Thank you!